# Extract ObjectId from mongo in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a project and my task is to extract ObjectId from MongoDb i.e. the id of each Document and use that in a JSONObject.

Comment: If you are using java, you could use some JPA implementation to map your class with the document, then you would have access to the Id's

Comment: Do you have an example? thanks

Comment: have a look here, https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ they use spring-boot which i would higlhy recommend to use in your project

Answer (score 0):

One way to chieve that in Java is by using Aggregation Pipeline.
For example:

```
List<Bson> aggregation = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                match(new Document(FIELD, VALUE)), //your match criteria
                project(new Document(FIELD1,0).append(FIELD2,0)...))); // hiding fields
                // _id field is by default included - so you have to exclude eveything else
```